# Can't access SSL on WordPress

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, bitnami

When I try to open file as mydomain.com/test.txt I get this msg:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access

for any file that as .txt

This is EC2 instance bitnami and I was installing wordpress. It works but I need to activate SSL access but I can't do this because when I go to `mydomain/.well-known/pki-validation/file.txt` I get the above error.

Comment: To where does `mydomain.com` point -- an EC2 instance? An S3 bucket? If it is an EC2 instance, are you running a web server on the instance (which one)? Are you saying that it successfully serves content if the extension is *not* .txt? Please Edit your question to provide more information. For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: EC2 instance and i'm was install wordpress it's work good i'm need to activate the ssl by method HTTP i'm can't do this becous when i'm go to 
http://mydomain/.well-known/pki-validation/file.txt 
i'm get error 
You don't have permission to access /.well-known/pki-validation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was

whene i'm try to open any file .txt i'm get error 403 ,

for example 
mydomain/.well-known/pki-validation/file.txt
i'm get the error 403 ...

i'm solve it by add this code in httpd.conf

```
<Files ~ "\.txt$">
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Require all granted
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about how to enable HTTPS support with SSL certificates in the [Bitnami Documentation Page](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/#how-to-enable-https-support-with-ssl-certificates). Can you try to follow this guide to try to configure SSL in your WordPress installation?

Comment: thanks for your comment but this is not of my issue , them was  change the text but this changes not correct .